# Swagger UI - Unable to infer base url in Swagger 2.9.2

Tags: java, eclipse, rest, swagger, swagger-ui

So, I just started using Swagger two days ago, I saw a video about how to configure a basic Swagger documentation on my API. The video just tells you to create a new class with this code:

```
@Bean
    public Docket api() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("your-api-package")
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }
```

I downloaded the spring-instrument.jar and added it to my project. Added the dependencies in pom.xml and that's about it. Then the Unable to infer base url error appeared when I tried to access localhost/my-project/swagger-ui.html. Looked up online and found that I needed to add the Swagger Security too, so I ended up downloading the spring-security.jar. I created a SwaggerSecurity class with this code:

```
private static final String[] AUTH_LIST = {
        "/swagger-resources/**",
        "/swagger-ui.html",
        "/v2/api-docs",
        "/webjars/**"
};

protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    http
    .authorizeRequests().antMatchers(AUTH_LIST).authenticated()
    .and()
    .httpBasic().authenticationEntryPoint(swaggerAuthenticationEntryPoint())
    .and()
    .csrf().disable();
}

@Bean
public BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint swaggerAuthenticationEntryPoint() {
    BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint entryPoint = new BasicAuthenticationEntryPoint();
    entryPoint.setRealmName("Swagger Realm");
    return entryPoint;
}
```

Which appeared to solve the problem for some people, but the error is still there. So I would like to know if someone has experienced this too and how did you guys solve the problem. I don't know if it adds anything to my question, but I'm using the latest Eclipse version to run the project.

Answer (score 0):

Lots of things not clear in your question but let me try.

If you are running spring app with embedded tomcat then you need to define servlet context path. Just add below line in your `src/main/resources/application.properties`

```
server.servlet.context-path=/my-project
```

And try running again, It should work.
If it stills doesn't work, try modifying your `Docket` bean definition as:

```
@Autowired
private  javax.servlet.ServletContext servletContext;

@Bean
public Docket api() {
    return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
            .pathProvider(new springfox.documentation.spring.web.paths.RelativePathProvider(servletContext) {
                  @Override
                  protected String applicationPath() {
                      return "/my-project";
                  }
            })
            .select()
            .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("your-api-package"))
            .paths(PathSelectors.any())
            .build();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Add below dependencies:

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.2</version>
        </dependency>
```

Extend `WebMvcConfigurationSupport` in your project and override ***addResourceHandlers***.

```
@Configuration
@EnableSwagger2
public class SwaggerConfig extends WebMvcConfigurationSupport {

    @Bean
    public Docket productApi() {
        return new Docket(DocumentationType.SWAGGER_2)
                .select()
                .apis(RequestHandlerSelectors.basePackage("your-base-package"))
                .paths(PathSelectors.any())
                .build();
    }

    @Override
    protected void addResourceHandlers(ResourceHandlerRegistry registry) {
        registry.addResourceHandler("swagger-ui.html")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/");
        registry.addResourceHandler("/webjars/**")
                .addResourceLocations("classpath:/META-INF/resources/webjars/");
    }
}
```

Annotate `@Api` and `@ApiOperation` in your controller.

```
@RestController
@Api(tags = {"Hello controller"})
@RequestMapping(value = "api")
public class HelloController {

    @ApiOperation(value = "greet")
    @GetMapping(value = "/greet", consumes = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<String> index() {
        return ResponseEntity.ok("Greetings from Spring Boot!");
    }
}
```

This works like a charm. Start your service. Hit [localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html](http://localhost:8080/swagger-ui.html) from the browser.